# Use AngularCLI to generate components when there are multiple apps in your project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

My .angular-cli.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "suman-chrome-extension"
  },
  "apps": [

    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
    },
    {
      "root":"blank-page-src",
      "outDir": "blank-page-dist",
      "index": "page.html",
      "main": "page.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "blank-page",
    },

    {
      "root":"dev-tools-src",
      "outDir": "dev-tools-dist",
      "index": "suman-dev-tools.html",
      "main": "suman-dev-tools.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "suman-dev-tools",
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I use a command like this:

```
ng g service services/foo
```

it will put this service in the first app. This occurs even if I `cd` into a subdirectory.

How can I generate components/services etc in an app other than the main/first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give each of them a name like following

`.angular-cli.json`

```
apps: [
    {
        ...
        "name": "app-1"
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "name": "app-2"
        ...
    }
]
```

Then, you can create your components/services/pipes/modules like following

`ng g c my-component --app=app-1`

Or if you don't want to name them (which you should), you can use index as well like following

`ng g c my-component --app=0` --> creates a component in the first app

`ng g c my-component --app=1` --> creates a component in the second app

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Angular 17 right now and you can also use the flag `--project=app-name` like this:

```
ng generate component componentName --project=app-name
```

It generates a component named "componentName" in the app "app-name"

---

As a bonus for newbies like me, you can create a project with no applications using:

```
ng new MultipleProyects --create-application="false"
```

Then you add new apps with:

```
ng generate application app-name-one
ng generate application app-name-two
```

This creates a folder named "projects" which contains your apps, those use the same installation of Angular, which means you won't need to install all the Angular libraries each time you create a new app.

Also, to serve an application you use:

```
ng serve --project=app-name-one
```