# How to create components through command line when there are multiple projects (Angular CLI 6)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm using latest **Angular CLI version (v6)**. I have multiple apps in the same code inside the **projects** folder.

I want to generate **modules and components** inside those projects using **command line**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved as below.

```
ng generate module my-module --project=my-project1 --> creates a module in project1

ng generate component my-component--project=my-project1 --> creates a component in project1
```

Check my blog post for more information [here](http://angular-with-fun.blogspot.com/2018/08/customized-versions-of-your-app-using.html).

If you are using CLI old version (V1) check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759741/use-angularcli-to-generate-components-when-there-are-multiple-apps-in-your-proje)

Comment: and how to create a component in a module of the project so it will be added to that module and added to the exports of the project?